# How do you like to be managed?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, wh-questions

I would like to know the meaning of this question, "*How do you like to be managed?*" is it regarding:

1. requesting an opinion about how you feel about being managed: if you like or not be under management.
2. requesting a description of the way that you like to be managed: what way you like to be treated.

The reason for the question is from an older post of mine: ["How do you like to be when...?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316555/how-do-you-like-to-be-when) if I put that pattern question, is it going to mean: What way do you like to be when...? I would like to know if grammatically not naturally, this question is well-formed:

> *How do you like to be when a business colleague get(s) close to you?*

The meaning I'm trying to convey is: what kind of personality you take when a business colleague approach(es) you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very common for someone to ask another person how they liked being managed (i.e., the first point you mentioned). And at the same time, it is far more common for, say, a new manager to ask their inferiors what management strategy they prefer. Thus, by virtue of frequency, the sentence in question should be a request for description (as you put it).

However, if in the rare case that you do intend the first meaning, it would do well to put it slightly more clearly. For instance, you could make it simpler by asking:

> How do you like *being managed*?

Or clearer still, by saying:

> *Do you like being managed?*

While on the subject, I should like to bring up the fact that there could also be a third meaning of this sentence, that being a sarcastic remark, as in the way one would say:

> How did you like *that*?

Of course, I do realise this is a very specific scenario in which one is perhaps giving someone else a taste of their own medicine.